# Accesing the stored text file in the "Text Edit", Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt, text, edit

I create a Qt Gui application with a "pushbutton" and a "text edit". I wanna assign the text in "text edit" to a QString variable after click on the "pushbutton". How can i store this text in a QString variable ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And why do you need a file?
Just this:

```
QString foo = ui->textEdit->toPlainText();
```

Also you need to connect signal "clicked" of QPuhsButton and created slot to get text.

Comment: Thanks i will try. I want to create a basic text editor.I don't know how to do it in the best way.I store it in a variable and save it in a .txt file.

Comment: I hope this tutorial helps:
[TextEditor tutorial](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.2/mainwindows-application.html)

Comment: That's ugly, not intuitive API, should be just getText()

Answer (score 0):

if you have a file and want to store it in a QString when cklicking a button, you can do that using QFileDialog 
for example:

```
//includes
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QFile>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QMessageBox>

// then in the Button,you can use this
 QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,
    tr("Open File"), "/home", tr("code file (*.txt)"));// string has the file link
// if you using Windows OS replace "/home" with "c://"
QFile file(fileName);
if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    QMessageBox::information(0,"info",file.errorString());
QTextStream in(&file); 
QString ex=in.readAll();
```

now you have all things in the file stored in QString.
note that you can replace .txt with any extension you need and also you can add extensions